# siunitx with svg graphics

Tags: siunitx, svg

I am using pdfLaTeX (TeX Live 2011) to compile a document. Unfortunately it does not compile. Again, my example compiles flawlessly with TeX Live 2009.
I include an SVG/PDF graphics following [this guide](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/documentation/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf). To do so I first create a drawing in an SVG file, then I export it to PDF and `pdf_tex` files.

In the SVG file I added a line of text like this:

```
\SI{6}{\arcsecond}
```

The figure is included by:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\def \svgwidth{\columnwidth}
\includesvg{path-to-figure}
\caption{\SI{6}{\metre}}
\label{fig:label-of-figure}
\end{figure}
```

The  `\includesvg` command is defined as:

```
\newcommand{\executeiffilenewer}[3]{% 
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\pdffilemoddate{#1}}% 
  {\pdffilemoddate{#2}}>0% 
    {\immediate\write18{#3}}\fi%
} 
\newcommand{\includesvg}[1]{%
\executeiffilenewer{#1.svg}{#1.pdf}{% 
inkscape -z -D --file=#1.svg %
--export-pdf=#1.pdf --export-latex}%
\input{#1.pdf_tex}%
}
```

Parts of the generated `pdf_tex` file.

```
\begin{picture}(1,0.44809873)%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{snifs_fov.pdf}}%
    \put(0.47868192,0.06651686){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{c) foo + bar + baz }}}%
    \put(0.47868192,0.17904892){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{b) bar + baz }}}%
    \put(0.47868192,0.33397134){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{a) baz}}}%
    \put(0.01018567,0.21107977){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{\SI{6}{\arcsecond}}}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

This is the resulting error.

```
(./figs/graphics/snifs_fov.pdf_tex
<./figs/graphics/snifs_fov.pdf, id=104, 376.15532pt x 168.55472pt>
<use ./figs/graphics/snifs_fov.pdf>)
! Undefined control sequence.
\arcsecond ->\ERROR
```

**UPDATE:**
I have mistakenly considered the SVG file to be the root of the error. In fact the same text, which is in the SVG file, follows in a paragraph after the figure. I debugged this by changing the text in the SVG file. The error message after compilation did not change. And also JosephWright's confirmation, that it is possible to compile the file in an MWE, helped me to find out.

Comment: Exactly which `siunitx` version do you have: check in your log file. I can test against any version: you may be seeing a bug in an old version. (This is a more general point: TeX Live versions don't really tell us much about individual package versions, which are almost always more informative.)

Comment: siunitx.sty    2012/05/03 v2.5c A comprehensive (SI) units package

Comment: The file http://depositfiles.com/files/86r22v83r

Comment: No problems here with a minimal `.tex` file, the linked SVG converted using Inkscape and the version of `siunitx` you cite.

Comment: I must have mistakenly suspected the svg file to be the root of the problem.

Comment: Please put your files somewhere that doesn't ask for mobile numbers etc. advertisement pages. There are many other options like pastebin etc. for free and free of adware.

Comment: sorry, I did not know that one could upload files to pastebin,too. I also share your view that depositfiles is annoying.

Comment: You can paste your svg file content and we can save it without any problems. That would avoid downloads etc. automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(More of a comment, but too long.)  For me, using

```
\documentclass{article}
\listfiles
\usepackage{siunitx,graphicx}
\newcommand{\executeiffilenewer}[3]{% 
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\pdffilemoddate{#1}}% 
  {\pdffilemoddate{#2}}>0% 
    {\immediate\write18{#3}}\fi%
} 
\newcommand{\includesvg}[1]{%
%\executeiffilenewer{#1.svg}{#1.pdf}{% 
%inkscape -z -D --file=#1.svg %
%--export-pdf=#1.pdf --export-latex}%
\input{#1.pdf_tex}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \includesvg{snifs_fov}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and a `.pdf_tex` file created using Inkscape works fine (I don't have it on my path, so did the conversion in the GUI). Works with both `siunitx` v2.5c and latest release.